# Is a Common Lisp bordeaux-threads lock equivalent to Java synchronization?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, common-lisp

I'm coming from a Java background trying to wrap my head around some common Lisp code that uses [`with-recursive-lock-held`](https://github.com/sionescu/bordeaux-threads/blob/master/src/default-implementations.lisp#L155). Now I studied Operating Systems in Computer Science at university - so I'm familiar with the concept of thread locks at theoretical level. My question is more at the practical end.

Suppose we have the [following Common Lisp code](https://github.com/danlentz/printv/blob/master/lock.lisp#L35-40):

```
(progn 
  (defun make-recursive-lock (&optional name)
    (sb-thread:make-mutex :name (or name "printv")))
  (defmacro with-recursive-lock-held ((place) &body body)
    `(sb-thread:with-recursive-lock (,place)
      ,@body)))
```

To me this appears to open and hold a lock at the operating system thread level.

If I try and express this idea in Java (to wrap my head around it) - I get something like:

```
public class SyncronizedExample {
    private long protectedLong = 0;
    private Object sync1 = new Object();

    public void inc1() {
        synchronized(sync1) {
            protectedLong++;
        }
    }
}
```

(There is an assumption I'm using 'old-school' Java [synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html), and not the [newer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html) [Locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) from `java.util.concurrent.*`- come with me on this - I'm trying to keep things as simple as possible).

(I'm also assuming the Common Lisp example is a macro and the Java example is just a data structure with a sync around it, and that these are not directly comparable. This is partially because macros in the Java language are not possible, but also because I assume you're an intelligent reader, and can look at the ideas and not the syntax.)

My question is: **Is a Common Lisp bordeaux-threads lock equivalent to Java synchronization?**

Comment: Those macros look like a very thin adapter for functions in the `sb-thread` namespace.  The interesting part is what those sb-thread functions do.  I don't know bordeaux-threads, so I can only guess, based on the names, that you are right: They do the same as what your Java code example does.

Comment: "...the Java example is just a data structure with a sync around it."  `synchronized` is part of the Java language.  A `synchronized(foo) {...}` construct is a _statement_, just like `if(i<10) { ... }` is a statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following aspects, yes:

- They work on the thread level.
- They provide a reentrant lock (you have the option of not using a *recursive* lock in Lisp, though).

In the following aspects, maybe:

- The implementation will vary in the details.  SBCL uses CAS to grab a mutex, I don't know how other Common Lisp implementations do it.  Java does not, as far as I know.

In the following aspects, no:

- You used one lock holder per `SyncronizedExample` (sic) on the Java side.  Using a class variable instead would make the example more similar.

Aside:

- Use `&optional (name "printv")` to give a default value to an optional parameter.
- I see no need of your Lisp forms for the wrapping `progn`.
- Use the library `bordeaux-threads` (available from Quicklisp) as a portability wrapper for low level thread code.
- Instead of wrapping the Lisp calls to `make-mutex` and `with-recursive-lock` in superfluous wrappers, you could show how you would call them.
- You could show how you would call the Java code.